# How to add Arguments while debugging php scripts in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

While debugging a PHP script in eclipse, I don't see an option to pass Arguments to the script. But I do see the option for JAva applications.

Is this feature not supported by eclipse yet? Or is there a way and I am missing it?

I am using Helios Eclipse for PHP.

thanks.

Comment: there may be "run configuration" in the run menu, there is for zend based on eclipse, you could just 'fake' them in the sript.

Comment: the run and debug configurations allow for arguments only for java applications; not for php scripts. hence the question.

Comment: well in zend studio the options are there for php as well, if not in Helios, then i guess you cant.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Eclipse Indigo with PDT and there's an option in Run >> Debug Configurations >> PHP CLI Application >> YOUR_CUSTOM_CONFIGURATION >> PHP Script Arguments (the 2nd tab).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the arguments via the debug URL like so:

```
http://example.com?x=z&a=b
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a few gray hairs growing on this question, but I ran into the same issue.

I'm using Zend Studio 11.

My solution was to use Alternate PHP (CLI) instead of Project Default PHP (CGI) in the Debug Configurations dialog to get the contents of the PHP Script Arguments tab to register properly.  When using the CGI mode, my arguments were getting attached to the end of the debugger arguments and didn't register.